# Group notifications by id and display like Whatsapp

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, firebase-notifications, react-native-firebase

I've been trying to group notifications by an *id* to have them displayed as WhatsApp for example, without having one notification per line.

Adding `setGroup` in either `onNotification` or `onNotificationDisplayed` seems to have no effect see examples below:

1

```
componentDidMount() {
this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification(async (notification) => {
  // Process your notification as required
  notification.android.setAutoCancel(true)

  notification.android.setGroup(notification.data.channelId)
  notification.android.setGroupSummary(true)
} 
}
```

2

```
componentDidMount() {
this.notificationDisplayedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationDisplayed((notification) => {
   notification.android.setGroup(notification.data.channelId)
  notification.android.setGroupSummary(true)
});
}
```

Any idea how can I group them by id?

Comment: Are you sure notification.data.channelId remains the same for every notification?

Comment: yes, it;s the same for every notification

Answer (score 0):

how about this:-

```
componentDidMount() {
    var zero = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
        this.setState({
            channelId=notification.data.channelId,
            Title=notification.data.Title,
            Body=notification.data.Body
//basically get all the data from the notification the you receieve from notification into states.
        });
    });
    if(this.state.channelId === "WhatsApp"){
        this.notificationDisplayedListener = 
            notification.android.setAutoCancel(true)
            notification.android.setTitle(this.state.Title)
            notification.android.setBody(this.state.Body)
            notification.android.setGroup(this.state.channelId)
            notification.android.setGroupSummary(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply but the code you've sent seems unrelated to the problem i ve described